# Integrating a jQuery Slider mess up the design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a bit of trouble integrating ResponsiveSlider in my page as each type that I integrate it the design is messed up. The div under goes up and hide under the slider, the text goes down etc... the all page in fact.

you can find a live version [here](http://miluge.delphinus.uberspace.de/Jack_Foster_Final/)

Sorry for the eye-bleeding I'm trying to learn but keeping my code clean wasn't really my priority :/

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="head">
      <header>
        <img src="http://html5hub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/default-share1.png" alt="photo profile">
        <ul>
          <li><h1>Jack Foster</h1></li>
          <li>7 Beer Street, London</li>
          <li>Phone : 00000456789</li>
          <li>contact@youdontknowjack.com</li>
        </ul>
      </header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
       <!--Problem  down here-->
      <ul class="rslides">
          <li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
          <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
          <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <div class="content">
      <div id="history-back">
        <div id="history">
      <h2>History & Profile</h2>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="skill">
      <h2>Skillset</h2>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="studies-back">
    <div id="studies">
      <h2>Studies</h2>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="work">
      <h2>Work</h2>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div>
        <ul style="list-style: none">
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
        <ul style="list-style: none">
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
        <ul style="list-style: none">
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </footer>
      </div>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
  });
</script>
```

And the crappy CSS I wrote :

```
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
.container {
  width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  background: #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #bbbbbb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #bbbbbb;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #bbbbbb;
  height: 100%
}
body {
    color: black;
    background: #eacece;
    background: url(../images/tilepng.png);
}
body h2 {
  font: ;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
header {
    position: relative;
}
header h1 {
  font-style: ;
}
header ul {
  padding: 3px;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-top: 4em;
}
header li {
  display: block;
}
nav ul {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #F9F9F9;
    }
nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
#history-back {
      min-height: 150px;
      max-height: 200px;
      background: url(../images/tilegif.gif);
      }
#history {
      margin: 3em;
      display: inline-block;
      }
#skill {
        background: #ffffff;
      margin: 3em 3em 3em 3em;
}
#studies-back {
        min-height: 150px;
      max-height: 200px;
        background: url(../images/tilegif.gif);
}
#studies {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 3em 3em 3em 3em;
      display: inline-block;
}
#work {
        background-color: #ffffff;
      margin: 3em;
      margin-bottom: 3em;
}
footer { background: #313131; width: 960px; height: 100%}
footer div { background: #313131; width:290px; padding: 15px; float:left; text-align: center}

/* rslides styles */
.rslides {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.rslides li {
position: absolute;
display: none;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
}

.rslides img {
display: block;
height: auto;
float: left;
width: 100%;
border: 0;
}
```

Far from being perfect but it gets the job done, if you have anything to add to ease it out feel free to do it.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I will edit this asap. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images are floating you need to clear the container below it.

```
.content {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Just did it and it worked! I spent maybe 2 hours changing everything in the css and just a clear: both make the whole headache go away!

Answer (score 1):

Your content class and the slider classes are overlapping, but the slider's content is pushing content's content down.  The size of the ul holder for the slider is smaller than what is in the slider, and the content div is aligning with that and not what's in the li tags.

For a styling fix, you can apply padding to the top of content for a quick fix, or give your ul the appropriate size of the pictures you're trying to slide through.  I'm not familiar with this particular plug in though, so I'm not sure if there is a scripting fix or not.  You might be able to specify a container height when you initialize.